# Relay chunked response in Proxy

Tags: c#, http, proxy, fiddlercore

I just wrote an SSL supporting HTTP 1.1/1.0 proxy putting together some code for past two days. I used the HTTPWebResponse/HTTPWebRequest class to get the data from the Server. While relaying data from the server I send the headers first to the browser as soon as I have it and the then the response stream from the server. I noticed that when the response is Chunked if I just read using `HTTPWebresponse.GetResponseStream()` using a stream reader and forward it to the browser, the browser fails to load the page. After spending some time I realized that `GetResponseStream()` seems to be already de-chunked, so the browser fails to parse it (since the chunked response header is already sent to the browser which confused it). I made a workaround by removing the chunked header and then sending the `responsestream` together without chunking.

But I noticed that *fiddlercore* (royalty-free proxy library) somehow relays the chunked data without doing the workaround I did, it is written in .NET, so I suppose there should be a way to relay the chunks one by one.

My question is how to relay chucked response properly in a proxy when using streams?  Also if my proxy is intended for the local machine does the performance would be poor if I sent the data together to the browser without chunking (while proxy uses chunking with the server and vice-versa when requested)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually decided to chunk the data again each time I read in to the buffer from the responsestream (only if the response header is indicating a chunked response). I suppose the performance penalty in re-chunking would be negligible. If I just waited for all the chunks to be read as I mentioned in workaround, then there is a possibility that I would blow up the memory available to proxy.

Answer (score 0):

FiddlerCore is a complete implementation of the HTTP/1.1 protocol, written directly atop TCP/IP sockets.

As such, it doesn't suffer from the limitations inherent in the higher-level WebRequest classes (at the cost of the fact that I had to completely implement the protocol myself).

Comment: Okay Eric. Actually my proxy works with almost same performance as fiddlercore. I undestand the implementation issue, just curious.

Comment: Haven't made an extensive testing though, not claiming its better than fiddler..:-)

Comment: The key attribute of FiddlerCore isn't performance (which is fine)-- it's instead *compatibility*. It's quite difficult to implement a proxy which supports all of the quirks of browsers and servers.

Comment: I agree, I actually just modified an article on code project to support HTTP 1.1 with keep-alive and chunking. The build in .net classes made life easier. But fiddler uses TCP/IP directly and I can see its strength. Its a great tool I use in my work to debug. Great work!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93301/Implementing-a-Multithreaded-HTTP-HTTPS-Debugging

Comment: The codeproject article linked above has significant bugs in it; I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Well its not perfect, I fixed the bugs and worked great for me. I just put the link here since there is not much tutorials on writing proxy in C#. With minimal changes in it I was able to support all features of HTTP 1.1.

Comment: I think it's pretty unlikely that it supports "all features" of HTTP/1.1. How about pipelining?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I thought pipe-lining is for future HTTP. My requirement was satisfied though.